# React-Native / Google Pay / Braintree / return error code "field":"authorizationFingerprint","code":"93201"

Tags: react-native, payment, braintree, google-pay, react-native-google-pay

Google Payment is **activated** on **sandbox.braintreegateway.com**
Used packages for payment:

- "react-native-payments"
- "com.google.android.gms:play-services-wallet:19.0.1"

> android/build.gradle
>
> ```
> buildscript {
>  repositories {
>         google()
>         jcenter()
>         mavenCentral()
>  }
> }
>
> allprojects {
>  repositories {
>         mavenLocal()
>  }
> google()
> jcenter()
> mavenCentral()
> maven { url 'https://www.jitpack.io' }
> }
> ```

This is my configuration where I use braintreeClientToken which is returned from server and also I use Merchant ID which I take from this page [https://sandbox.braintreegateway.com/merchants/{merchantID}/merchant_accounts/info](https://sandbox.braintreegateway.com/merchants/%7BmerchantID%7D/merchant_accounts/info)

```
const METHOD_DATA = [{
       supportedMethods: ['android-pay'],
       data: {
        supportedNetworks: ['visa', 'mastercard', 'amex'],
        allowedPaymentMethods: [1, 2],
        currencyCode: 'EUR',
        environment: 'TEST',
        countryCode: 'IT',
        paymentMethodTokenizationParameters: {
         tokenizationType: 'GATEWAY_TOKEN',
         parameters: {
          gateway: 'braintree',
          publicKey: braintreeClientToken,
         'braintree:apiVersion': 'v1',
         'braintree:merchantId': merchantID,
      },
     },
   },
 },
];
```

But when I finishing payment It returns error inside PaymentResponse.

"{"error":{"message":"Authorization fingerprint is invalid"},"fieldErrors":[{"field":"authorizationFingerprint","code":"93201","message":"Authorization fingerprint is required"}]}"

[image]